# How do I iterate through a [String:[String]] Dictionary in Swift

Tags: dictionary, swift2

I have a dictionary.

```
var params: [String: [String]] = [:]
```

I assign an array to the first key and the first key only. Now print params prints :

```
["names" : ["jack", "joe", "jill"]]
```

How do I iterate through this array at this given key so that I could loop through and print jack, joe, and jill?

Comment: for (_, value) in params { value.forEach{print($0)} }

Comment: `params["names"]?.forEach({print($0)})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (key, names) in params {
    for name in names {
        print("\(name))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var params: [String: [String]] = ["names" : ["jack", "joe", "jill"]]
            for key in params.keys {
                NSLog("%@", key)
                let list = params[key]
                for obj in list! {
                    NSLog("%@", obj)
                }
            }
```

Using tuples:

```
let params: [String: [String]] = ["names" : ["jack", "joe", "jill"]]
        for (key, names) in params {
            print("\(key)")
            for name in names {
                print("\(name)")
            }
        }
```